# What does -gt do in shell (bash)?

Tags: bash

I've been looking everywhere on the Internet but can find what -gt does in bash. Any help is appreciated. If you need an example here:

```
while test $# -gt 0
do
    arg="$1"; shift
done
```

Comment: For `test`, it's a command line argument for "greater than" see: `$ man test`

Answer (score 0):

Greater than

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119546/starting-with-bash-lt-and-gt-arguments

First page of a google search BTW